# Different users Access front end generating different SQL for backend

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

Here's my situation:

- Both users are using the same Microsoft Access front end.
- Both users have the same version of the SQL Server Native Client 10.0 ODBC driver.
- Both users have the same version of Microsoft Office 2007 installed.
- Both users are opening the same report with the same parameter values.
- One takes 2 minutes, the other takes an hour.
- The issue travels with the user, it happens regardless of which PC they log into on the network.

I checked the SQL passed to SQL Server and it is different. The one that runs quickly is standard T-SQL. The one that hangs is sending a parameterized query that has a terrible execution plan. I can't figure out what is causing it to send one query for one user and a different query for another user.

Since the issue travels with the user regardless of which PC they are on. This makes me think that it is some sort of obscure group policy setting or active directory setting that is part of the users account that is being replicated from PC to PC. Which probably means it's in the registry somewhere. But I am having a difficult time tracking down what that registry key is. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I might be a good idea to post the two different SQL statements. - If the issue has been resolved in the meantime, it would be nice if you would post the solution.

Comment: For one user, it sends it as "select ... from tablename where fieldname = value" while for the other user, it sends it as "(@param) select ... from tablename where fieldname = @param".